# Why do my txt files on VScode show up as full of errors?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, requirements.txt

[image: Screenshot]

Whenever I open a new window/project that has a .txt file, it shows up full of errors. In the explorer tab, the file shows up as red and if I open it, each line shows underlined as red.

Did anyone encounter the same issue? If so how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance!

I tried closing VSCode and opening it again. Other than that, I don't know much how to debug this issue.

Comment: Open the problems tab and it should tell you why it is highlighting those lines.  Also hovering the mouse over one of them should get you some info.

Comment: The syntax is set to Python rather than plaintext. Change in bottom right

Comment: Somehow it thinks this txt file is actually a python file.

Comment: So what are these error messages? Also show a full screenshot containing the text type recognized by vscode in the bottom right corner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to edit visual code settings for the file extension itself instead of restarting the app. Syntax highlighting is a feature not an issue.

Instead go to bottom right and select the language used (python would be selected in your case)
[image]
Now when you click it you should have a menu open up to select the interpreter to associate with the file.
[image]
Here you can type in your file type to select one type to associate with your current file only or select `configure File assocation for '.txt'` to set the language that will be used for this file type every time.

For your file type requirements.txt the best options are `plain text` or `pip requirements`
[image][image]